# "Free" resolution of algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, simplicial-stuff

Given a ring $R$, we have an adjunction of the forgetful functor $CAlg_R\to Set$ and the free algebra functor $Set\to CAlg_R$, giving us an endofunctor $$T:CAlg_R\to CAlg_R, S\mapsto R[S].$$

In general any adjuction of a forgetful functor $\mathcal{C} \to Set$ and a free functor $Set\to \mathcal{C}$ yields such an endofunctor $\mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{C}$.

This in particualr yields
$$\ldots  R[R[S]]\rightrightarrows R[S]\to S$$
which we call a free resolution. What can we say about $\text{colim} T^i(S)$? When is this isomorphic to $S$? What can we say for a general bar-resolution coming from a monad?

Comment: Let $T$ be a monad on $C$ and let $S$ be the comonad induced on $C^T$. Then every $X∈C^T$ is the coequalizer of the two morphisms $S^2(X)⇉S(X)$. This is the subject of Beck monadicity theorem and related developments. But maybe you wanted to know when the bar-resolution coming from a *comonad* ($T$ in your post) gives what you want? Are you interested only in the comonads on $C^T$ built from $T$?

Comment: Related link: https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2007/05/on_the_bar_construction.html